# How can I stream an image from node-webshot to filepicker

Tags: node.js, filepicker.io, html5-filesystem, fs

Node webshot is used to take a picture of an external website. The node webshot API is:

```
var webshot = require('webshot');
var fs      = require('fs');

webshot('google.com', function(err, renderStream) {
  var file = fs.createWriteStream('google.png', {encoding: 'binary'});

  renderStream.on('data', function(data) {
    file.write(data.toString('binary'), 'binary');
  });
});
```

I am confused about file.write. Is the file being stored in the file object?

I want to be able to use filepickers rest API to upload the image like so:

```
curl -X POST -F fileUpload=@filename.txt https://www.filepicker.io/api/store/S3?key=MY_API_KEY
```

But I am confused as how to integrate webshot with renderStream with filepicker without saving  the file to disk first. When the file is in memory I want to immediately send it to filepicker then get rid of it from memory.

Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about filepicker, but here is an example that streams the file to S3.

https://github.com/brenden/node-webshot/issues/90

Comment: Thanks, just what was looking for ;)